# Past Simple without specified time

Tags: present-perfect, past-simple, past-vs-past-perfect

I saw the following two sentence:

> The oldest person I met was 90 years old.

Is it correct? Or would it be better as:

> The oldest person I've met was 90 years old.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **the oldest person I met was  90 yers old**
>
> **The oldest person I  have met is 90 years old**
>
> **The oldest person I have met was 90 years old**

The  third sentence is not possible.

The first sentence means **you met a person who was 90 years old.You do not know about him now.He may be alive or dead or more than 90 now**

The  second sentence means **you  have met  a person who is 90 years old. you know him now. He is still 90 now**

Comment: I thought the same, its more likely, he is dead by now, so 'I met was' sounds better. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

the oldest person I met was 90 years old:  to me this implies that at an unspecified time in the past at some occasion you met people, and the oldest one was 90 years old.

the oldest person I have met is 90 years old means that up until this moment in your life, the oldest person you have met is 90 years old, so you have never met anyone older than 90.

the oldest person I had met was 90 years old: until a moment in your life in the past you had never met anyone older than 90.